# ANDROID DEV Calendar View with multi touch selection & days input

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm new to Android Development and I was asked to make an activity that shows a calendar (CalendarView). 
The idea is to have a calendar where it's possible to 'input' the number of hours worked in that day (4 or 8 are the possibilities) and:

- Only shows weeks WITHOUT weekends (from Monday to Friday)
- Allows multi-selection of the days
- Allows to write the 4/8 in the day

Any ideas?

I was able to create a normal calendar, but I don't know what to do now.